# 親不見、愛無心 origin of this quote

Tags: simplified-characters, traditional-characters, traditional-vs-simplified

「親（亲）不見，愛（爱）無心，產（产）不生，廠（厂）空空，麵（面）無麥，運（ 运）無車，導（导）無道，兒（儿）無首，飛（ 飞）單翼，湧（涌）無力，只有魔，还是魔。」

Where does the quote above stem from? I have seen it numerous times, even looked for it but could not figure it out.

Comment: 呐，是崇尚繁体的某些人撰的文字游戏，嘲讽简体字失去了“内涵”。版本很多，摘其一如下： 親（亲）不見，愛（爱）無心，產（产）不生，廠（厂）空空，麵（面）無麥，運（ 运）無車，導（导）無道，兒（儿）無首，飛（ 飞）單翼，湧（涌）無力，...有雲（云）無雨，開關（开关）無門，鄉（乡）里無郎，聖（圣）不能聽也不能說，買（买）成鈎刀下有人頭，輪（ 轮）成人下有匕首，進（进）不是越來越佳而往井裏走，只有魔，還是魔……（下略） 另外，此文传到大陆以后，亦有人作文反驳： 党（黨）内无黑，团（團）中有才，国（國）含宝玉，爱（愛）因友存，美还是美，善还是善，虽丑（醜）无鬼，只不过台（臺）无吉，湾（灣）无言! 穷（窮）不躬，权（權）不佳，巩（鞏）不革。车（車）不行田，坚（堅）不称臣。无鹿亦能丽（麗），无巫亦能灵（靈），无水亦能灭（滅），无火亦能劳（勞），无曲亦能礼（禮），无手亦能击（擊）。办（辦）事左右不辛苦，垦（墾）荒何必靠豺狼。 实际上跟文字源流关系不大，就是两岸挖苦罢了。

Comment: 個人認為没失去內涵，而是內涵變了而已，從古至今中文雖然一直是象形字，但因為文化也有負責構築文字的筆劃，書體，意思等等，所以在不同年代不同文化時期都大同小異甚至完全不一，而且語言很多，不同語言用詞也不一。年代變了，價值觀也變了而且在這想法多樣化的年代，文字變了自然也會有對之想法不一的人，取個例子譬如說黑簡體字時說的‘兒無首’，中國現在提倡統一思想，小孩子不雖要有自己的想法，那無首其實是絕對合理的。但同時’進步是往佳走而不是往井裏走‘也是合理的，故步自封又何以進之？但又譬如說黑繁體字的’穷不躬‘，時勢為天子，未必貴也，貧為匹夫，未必賤也，穷人該努力而非卑躬屈膝，這絕對不會是錯誤的想法。但同時‘国只含宝玉‘，城牆只保護財物，而没保護人民，也没武器去守護家園，再有錢的皇朝也没落過，所以不能空有財力而無武力。同為中華文化的一部分，何解不兩邊都去學去了解，明明曾經都稱彼此為血濃於水的同胞，何解非得爭個你死我活？

Answer (score 3):

From the short amount of research that I did in the past hour, I managed to trace back to a news article from 2006 which said the origin was from a Old Taiwanese man that went back to China to visit his relatives twenty years ago and he said the words "親不見，產不生，廠空空，愛無心" after visiting and noticing the changes in Chinese characters. (edit: forgot about the link https://hk.news.appledaily.com/local/daily/article/20060330/5783200 )

This topic came out again when the United Nations declared the abandonment of traditional Chinese language in 2006, in which people in the net started adding more and more phrases afterwards.

I hope that this could sort of answer your question.

Comment: Thank you, can you add the news article text or a link?

Comment: yes please,links would help a lot :)

Comment: Not sure if this is the original news article?  http://chezmoibooks.blogspot.com/2016/04/blog-post_25.html

Comment: Can you cite a reference for "This topic came out again when the United Nations declared the abandonment of traditional Chinese language in 2006"?